# C++ - Cannot declare variable to be of abstract type

Tags: c++, openfoam

I'm trying to write some code in C++ (for OpenFOAM) but I'm getting the error given in the title for this bit of code:

```
// Copy set
void backup 
(
   const polyMesh& mesh,
   const word& fromName, 
   const topoSet& fromSet,
   const word& toName
)
{
   Info<< "Backing up " << fromName << " into " << toName << endl; 

   topoSet backupSet(mesh, toName, fromSet);

   backupSet.write();
}
```

The full error is:

```
faceSet.C:51:18: error: cannot declare variable ‘backupSet’ to be of abstract type ‘Foam::topoSet’
```

The error is in this line:

```
topoSet backupSet(mesh, toName, fromSet);
```

From looking this up, I think I understand that topoSet maybe should be declared as a constant but I tried this and it made no difference.

I have a few errors of similar nature but I'm just trying to understand how to fix this one.

Comment: Ok it's a few hundred lines and I'm not sure which part of it would be the best to include so I can send it as a file somehow? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, there is not. You are supposed to construct a [minimal testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), at least in part because this should have been one of your first pre-asking-on-the-internet debugging steps.

Comment: Not sure how you arrived at "maybe should be declared as a constant" from researching abstract classes!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, `topoSet` is actually a class from a framework (OpenFOAM), I don't think you should require converting all framework classes to MVCE for all questions regarding some framework. I don't say that the question is well-researched though.

Comment: @Petr: In this case, citing OpenFOAM as an unincluded dependency would be fine. More than anything I was responding in general to the OP's statement _"Ok it's a few hundred lines and I'm not sure which part of it would be the best to include so I can send it as a file somehow"_ as that's simply not how this works.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, agreed

Answer (score 2):

You can not create a [`topoSet`](http://foam.sourceforge.net/docs/cpp/a02641.html) instance, because it is an abstract class containing virtual non-implemented methods ([`maxSize()`](http://foam.sourceforge.net/docs/cpp/a02641.html#a9e34e1af90b094bc9f08d9e498c3dcb4) seems to be one of these). Even if there was no non-implemented (pure virtual) members, creating a `topoSet` instance would be wrong as you would lose all the information about what was the original type of `fromSet` and all the data it had above `topoSet`'s (this is akin to [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)).

I think that you should use one of [`topoSet::New()`](http://foam.sourceforge.net/docs/cpp/a02641.html#ac7fefe6e0d9de3b54ec67d22c8dff133) static functions (named constructors), or if all you need to do is to save it under a different name, then just twice use [`topoSet::rename()`](http://foam.sourceforge.net/docs/cpp/a02157.html#af41376d1e0031e06613d5ce3c740cf7d) (actually `regIOobject::rename()`).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `topoSet backupSet;` as that would be an attempt to instantiate a `topoSet` which you can't do as it's abstract.

You need to create an instance of a concrete derived class instead. You'll need to find something appropriate or create it yourself. If we assume that such a thing is called `foo` then you could use a pointer

`topoSet* backupSet = new foo(/*ToDo - parameters*/)`

or instantiate directory `foo backupSet(/*ToDo - parameters, omit the parentheses if there are no parameters*/)`.